# gpg: DBG: kbx_client_data_cmd: finished command with error: Not initialized

Tags: gnupg

I suddenly get the following error when using most gpg commands after deleting a stale lockfile and cannot understand the reason/how to proceed

```
~ > gpg --list-secret-keys                               
gpg: DBG: kbx_client_data_cmd: finished command with error: Not initialized
gpg: keydb_search_first failed: Not initialized
```

I've tried recovering the deleted file and using

```
gpgconf --kill gpg-agent
```

to fix the issue to no avail. This is the only command that works

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue after `rm -rf ~/.gnupg/` and was unable to find much info on the noted kbx client. The error message mentioned a/the keyboxd daemon for me, that does the key handling for gpg since some time ago. The man pages gave some info about an internal sqlite db for the corresponding keyboxd keyring, that had not been created by gpg after the `rm`. Reinstalling or manually creating the file did not solve the issue, but removing the folder again did.

Wanted to share this in case it helps others with this problem.